# While building ASP.NET Core web app I get "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, asp.net-core-mvc

> The model item passed into the `ViewDataDictionary` is of type `'WebApp.Models.Order'`, but this `ViewDataDictionary` instance requires a model item of type `'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApp.Models.Product]'.`

**Models**

Product.cs

```
namespace WebApp.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Order.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApp.Models
{
    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

HomeController.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApp.Models;

namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Product> Products = new List<Product> {
                new Product {
                    Name = "Mobile Phone",
                    Price = 300
                },
                new Product {
                    Name = "Laptop",
                    Price = 1000
                },
                new Product {
                    Name = "Tablet",Price = 600
                }
            };
            Order order = new Order();
            order.Products = Products;
            order.Total = Products.Sum(product => product.Price);
            return View(order);
        }
    }
}
```

**Views**

Relative view page: Index.cshtml

```
@model List<WebApp.Models.Product>
<ul>
    @foreach (var Product in Model)
    {
        <li>@Product.Name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Partial view page: _Layout.cshtml

```
@model WebApp.Models.Order
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var Product in Model.Products)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Product.Name</td>
            <td>@Product.Price</td>
        </tr>
    }
    <tr>
        <td><b>Total</b></td>
        <td><b>@Model.Total</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Layout setter page: _Viewstart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Your `_Layout` view is rendered for every page.  You are saying that your layout requires a `Order`.  So, the way you are set up, every model returned must be a subclass of `Order`

Comment: The view requires a `List<Product>` but in your controller you return a single Order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is expecting a list of products:

```
@model List<WebApp.Models.Product>
```

You are passing it an order:

```
return View(order);
```

If the rest of your view also uses the order, then it sounds like you just need to change your model declaration on the view:

```
@model WebApp.Models.Order
```

And loop through the products on that model:

```
@foreach (var Product in Model.Products)
```

---

What's **strange** is that you're trying to do this in your *layout*.  Don't do that.  The layout is just dressing around the page to be applied to every page.  It shouldn't require anything from the model.  The view itself should be bound to the model.